# cakephp checking for duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, caching

I have been at this for 5 days now. I read all the answers I could here, I have tried any options I could I cannot find how to fix this cache issue.

I am using cakephp 2.4.4 which could be upgraded but I did not see my issue in any of the change.log
Percona MYSQL 5.6 Innodb

We have a model that we call in a loop to insert rows

```
App::import('Model', 'TableA');
$TableA = new TableA();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $TableA->InsertRow($row);
}
```

Then we have the Model for TableA

I added a Unique Index on TableA.Sku to avoid duplicate entry

```
class TableA extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'TableA';
    var $cacheQueries = false;
    var $validate = array();
    function InsertRow($data){
        $this->clear();
        try {
            $result = $this->find('first', array(
                'fields' => array(
                     'TableA.id',
                 ),
                 'conditions' => array(
                     'TableA.Sku' => $data['Sku'],
                 ),
            ));
            pr($result);
            if(!isset($result['TableA']['id'])){
                $data['TimeStamp'] = strtotime("now");
                $this->save($data);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            pr($e);
            $resultNow = $this->find('first', array(
                'fields' => array(
                     'TableA.id',
                 ),
                 'conditions' => array(
                     'TableA.Sku' => $data['Sku'],
                 ),
            ));
            pr($resultNow);
        }
   }
}
```

The first loop $Rows has multiple time the same sku following each other
the first loop insert the row
the 2nd loop gives:

```
array
(
)

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'tue026991015' for key 'Sku'
INSERT INTO `ki`.`TableA` (`Sku`, `TimeStamp`) VALUES ('tue026991015', 1453858976)

Array
(
    [TableA] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31951
        )
)
```

I am also running in Debug Mode 2

In the 2nd loop the query should return the id and the loop should not try to insert the row but it is not.
I added var $cacheQueries = false; on top of the Model to avoid cashing. I am at a loss as to why this behavior is happening and how to avoid any mysql cashing for this function.

Comment: Why not use a validation rule for testing the `Sku` is unique rather than re-inventing the wheel? If `Sku` always needs to be unique `TableA` should use the `isUnique` validation rule on the `Sku` field which would cause `save` to fail if it already exists. This would greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Adding a validation works just like adding a Unique Index on the mysql table works and that is what I have used as a work around. This confirms that find('first') is using caching..... The real question here is how do I disable caching for find('first')

Comment: Adding a validation rule is *not* the same as adding a unique index on the table. The validation rule will check the database first that the value hasn't already been used and will prevent the save query from running (as well as flag the error), just adding a unique index on the table will not prevent Cake from running the query which will cause the MySQL error to be thrown that you are seeing. You really should be doing this as a validation rule as otherwise you will not be catching these errors when you attempt to save data.

Comment: In regards to caching, are you sure this is happening? Have you checked the query log to see if the query is only being run once?

Comment: Point well taken on validation and I agree and started implementing validations.

Comment: Regarding caching issue. I am not 100% sure how to look at the cakephp query log ? I pr() the result of both query in the code above. the first pr returns an empty array (I am assuming this is because of the previous row lookup thus pulling from the cache. Then the 2nd pr() for the same query in the catch part returns the id ...... This is what made me conclude to cache query. I am gona research how to see cakephp query log and do testing.

Comment: So a little bit more about testing. 
I used in my model Validation and I am still getting exceptions from my try .. catch..
I then added 
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$db->fullDebug = true;
$log = $db->getLog();
$db->fullDebug = false;
to get the log and save it to a file when the behavior was throwing the exception.

I found that:
Validation query kicks in.
It is not cached (I was wrong thinking it was cached).
instead Validation triggers the exception and the exception is that the INSERT failed for duplicates

I am now testing by adding back the find('first') query to see if it is cached

Comment: Alright so after more debug and looking at the queries the 2 queries are indeed ran by cakephp and not cached by cake. BUT apparently the cache is coming from MYSQL returning the previous answer.
So the problem is that the query created by cake is of the form SELECT id From but should be SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM. So the real question is how to force cake to use SQL_NO_CACHE in the query

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the user clicks "refresh" data or happens when you fill out the form and add user data gives? Which method you use to collect the GET or POST data?

Comment: The array of data is loaded from an API call that gives us an Array.
That Array has duplicates but we want unique values in our table.
So we test if the Sku already exists in the table before inserting. the exception comes from the fact that we have a UNIQUE index (which fixed the duplicate issue for now) but still that should not happen.